# How can I know if the creation of a user with email and password was successful? and take actions

Tags: javascript, email, firebase, passwords

For example:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
      alert('The password is too weak.');
      exit;
    } else {
      alert(errorMessage);
      exit;
    }
    console.log(error);
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
  });
```

this only creates the user and verifies errors, but does not indicate if the user's creation was successful, since I need to take actions, such as saving the user's name in my database (if the user's creation was successful) or Redirect if the user's creation is successful.

**How can I take actions if was successful the user createUserWithEmailAndPassword?**

Comment: add a then() to the promise, you are only processing the catch()

Comment: Charlie's comment is indeed one way. But you'll typically want to do most of those actions by [listening to `onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed_in_user). For example: updating the profile in the database in response to `onAuthStateChanged()` ensures the profile is always up to date, instead of just when you first create the account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.then()` instead:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(result){
  // update your database
  }, function(error){
  // handle the error
});
```